# Adding text in Calendar View

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, calendarview

I was trying to add text in my calendar view, here is the example how i want it to be like

http://postimg.org/image/wf4gxz1dr/

My CalendarView is in Material Design CalendarView, here is the link of my calendarView

http://postimg.org/image/iid1z41z1/

Is it possible to add text in this material design or i have to do it with the basic calendarView like in 1st picture.?
Please tell me how can i mak it possible in these views.

Sorry i can't upload screenshots here.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

Last month I was able to implement a little calendar view using Caldroid https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid.

It's flexible to use and it's not so hard to get a custom calendar view as implementing `onDraw` from the `CalendarView`.

Check the view I created (just by following the documentation). Just create your own cell layout and implement it:

[image: Custom calendar view using Caldroid]

And of course you can go beyond that.

Comment: How to Solve this issue??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275601/display-the-list-of-events-within-the-calendar

Comment: Does this library support multiple languages like its shown in your screenshot?